# Why is _GrabTexture(texture of current frame buffer) always empty in my code and how do I fix it?

Tags: unity, c#, fragment-shader, shaderlab

*I am using Unity 2021.3.29 and the built-in render pipeline.

Here is a fragment shader I wrote that uses a grab pass to replicate an "average color" blend mode

```
Shader "2DSB/VertexColor" 
{
    Properties
    {
        [PerRendererData] _MainTex ("Base (RGB) Trans (A)", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Color ("Main Color", Color) = (1, 1, 1, 1)
    }

    SubShader
    {
        Tags {"Queue"="Transparent" "IgnoreProjector"="True" "RenderType"="Transparent"}
        ZWrite Off
        Lighting Off
        Cull Off
        Fog { Mode Off }
        //Previous: Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
        Blend SrcAlpha Zero
        LOD 100

        // Add GrabPass to capture the current frame buffer
        GrabPass { } // "_GrabTexture" is the name of the grabbed texture
        
        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert_vct
            #pragma fragment frag_mult
            #pragma fragmentoption ARB_precision_hint_fastest
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float4 _MainTex_ST;
            sampler2D _GrabTexture;
            float4 _GrabTexture_ST;
            float4 _Color;

            struct vin_vct
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float4 color : COLOR;
                float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f_vct
            {
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
                fixed4 color : COLOR;
                float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
                float2 screenspaceUV : TEXCOORD1; // Add screen space UV
            };

            v2f_vct vert_vct(vin_vct v)
            {
                v2f_vct o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.color = v.color;
                o.texcoord = v.texcoord;
                o.screenspaceUV = ComputeScreenPos(o.vertex).xy; // Compute screen space position
                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag_mult(v2f_vct i) : SV_Target
            {
                fixed4 srcColor = tex2D(_MainTex, i.texcoord) * i.color * _Color;
                fixed4 dstColor = tex2D(_GrabTexture, i.screenspaceUV); // Color from the frame buffer; Use screen space UV to sample
                
                // Custom logic to average the colors
                fixed4 finalColor = srcColor;
                if (any(dstColor.rgba > fixed4(0,0,0,0).rgba)) { // Why is this never true, even when there's overlap between game objects?
                    finalColor = (srcColor + dstColor) * 0.5; // Simple averaging
                    //Test: finalColor = fixed4(1,0,0,1);
                }

                return finalColor;
            }
            
            ENDCG
        } 
    }
}
```

The big problem is that the sampled `_GrabTexture` is always empty. I know this because this block was never true:

```
if (any(dstColor.rgba > fixed4(0,0,0,0).rgba)) { // Why is this never true, even when there's overlap between game objects?
    finalColor = (srcColor + dstColor) * 0.5; // Simple averaging
    //Test: finalColor = fixed4(1,0,0,1);
}
```

However, this has to be true for regions where there are overlapping game objects. What is the issue here? How do I correctly sample the current frame buffer's texture using `GrabPass` to implement an average colors blend mode?